# Firebase Cloud Firestore does not return data or errors

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am learning to use Firebase Firestore and I have created a list of items that I want to display in my app. When trying to load the list, I don't receive the data but I also don't get any error. I cannot display the data in the Log.  What could be happening?

```
fun getDriverData(): LiveData<MutableList<Driver>> {
    val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Driver>>()

    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("drivers").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            val listData = mutableListOf<Driver>()
            Log.i("repo","called")
            for (document in result) {
                
                val photoUrl = document.getString("photoUrl")!!
                val name = document.getString("name")!!
                val team = document.getString("team")!!
                Log.i("repo", "${document.id}} => ${document.data}")
                val driver = Driver(name,team,photoUrl)
                listData.add(driver)
            }
            mutableData.value = listData
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Log.i("repo", "getDriverData: ${it.message}")
        }
    return mutableData
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collection is actually called "drivers" - WITH the quotation marks.  Whatever is generating the documents here is using extra quota when building the name of the collection.

You could read them back by adding those quotes:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("\"drivers\"").get()
```

But you probably want to fix the code that generates the document to not add those quotes.